# Responsive SVG - viewport Intrinsic Dimensions

Tags: html, css, svg

Below follows a few relevant excerpts from the [SVG2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html):

**[8.3. The initial viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewportSpace)**

> The initial viewport's width, must be the value of the `width`
>   presentation attribute on the [outermost svg element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#TermOutermostSVGElement), unless the
>   following conditions are met:
>
> - the SVG content is a separately stored resource that is embedded by reference (such as the `object` element in HTML), or the **SVG content
>     is embedded inline within a containing document**;
> - and the referencing element or **containing document is styled using CSS**;
> - and there are [**CSS-compatible positioning properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) specified on the referencing element (e.g., the `object` element) or on the
>     containing document's [outermost svg element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#TermOutermostSVGElement) that are **sufficient
>     to establish the width of the viewport**.
>
> Under these conditions, the viewport's width must be established via
>   the positioning properties.
>
> [The same applies to height]

**[8.12. Intrinsic sizing properties of SVG content](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#SizingSVGInCSS)**

> The intrinsic aspect ratio must be calculated using the following algorithm. If the algorithm returns null, then there is no intrinsic aspect ratio.
>
> 1. If the `width` and `height` sizing properties on the `svg` element are
>      both absolute values:
>
>    1. return width / height
> 2. If an *SVG View* is active:
>
>    1. let *viewbox* be the viewbox defined by the active SVG View
>    2. return *viewbox*.width / *viewbox*.height
> 3. If the `viewBox` on the `svg` element is correctly specified:
>
>    1. let *viewbox* be the viewbox defined by the `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element
>    2. return *viewbox*.width / *viewbox*.height
> 4. return null

---

**The Code**

I made a hamburger button in svg, and I am trying to figure out exactly what is going on in terms of the dimensions of its viewport, since we specify it both with the svg presentation attributes, and with CSS.

```css
svg#ham-btn {
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  fill: #383838;
  width: 10vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="ham-btn" width="107.5px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    #ham-btn {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #ham-btn rect {
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r2 {
      transform: translate(118%, 0);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r1 {
      transform: translate(0%, 191.66%) rotate(36deg) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    #ham-btn:hover #r3 {
      transform: translate(0%, -191.66%) rotate(-36deg) scaleX(1.1);
    }
    
  </style>
  <rect id="r3" x="0" y="71.25%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
  <rect id="r2" x="0" y="42.5%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%"/>
  <rect id="r1" x="0" y="13.75%" width="100%" height="15%" rx="5%" />
</svg>
```

**The Question**

My solution is dependent on the fact that the *viewport* ratio (107.5 / 80) differs from the `viewBox` ratio (80 / 80). This is what causes the centering (via `preserveAspectRatio`). If you change the viewport aspect ratio, you will break the solution.

Hence, my question is: Why is setting dimensions in CSS not identical to setting it in the svg directly? Why do the CSS height and width not seem to overwrite the height and width specified in the SVG (as the first spec excerpt above indicates that it should).

**My Best Guess**

- The svg `width` / `height` presentation attributes define the svg element's intrinsic aspect ratio (as can be seen from the second spec excerpt above)
- Then, CSS overwrites that width and height completely (as can be seen from the first spec excerpt above)
- That explains why it is necessary to set the height explicitly to `auto` in CSS. If we had not done that, the height of the svg would fall back to the specified 80px, thus distorting the shape

Any thoughts on whether this guess is correct?

Comment: I think you got it, by the way what you face is the same with image also, if you set width/height attribute you have to overwrite both (even by setting auto) in order to keep the ratio considering the intrinsic dimension :https://jsfiddle.net/6k4jrvsa/

Comment: Is your SVG document inline or resides by a standalone SVG file?

Comment: In any case, please try to reduce your use case to a minimal example where your question still applies. It's impossible to tell where in the document tree your SVG document is embedded and how, and what role would the `body` element being a Flex container, play in all of this.

Comment: @amn Flex plays no role, it was just for centering. I modified the OP to be minimal.

Comment: If future visitors are interested, the final button (with full accessibility features) can be found here: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/KrrJKa

Comment: If you only set the `width` in CSS, then the height will still be controlled by the `height` attribute in the SVG.  It's like saying, "why does the `padding-left` not change when I set the `padding-top?"

Comment: Thanks @paullebeau . I think this case is a bit more complicated to understand, because the intrinsic ratio is defined by the presentation attributes, but not by the CSS properties. If you had not known how intrinsic aspect ratios are determined in SVG (cheaper 8) you might have wondered why we are being redundant and setting both the presentation attributes and the CSS properties, when the latter just overwrites the former.

Comment: I believe my "best guess" was the right solution, so hopefully it will help others in the future.

Comment: As the portion of the spec you quoted says, the intrinsic size is set by the `width` and `height` - if both are present.  Otherwise the `viewBox` plays a role.

Comment: Yep, 100%, I just wanted to make sure I had understood it correctly. Thanks for chipping in!